# Is the coefficient of restitution a constant? (/Validity over range)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, collision

We were taught about coefficient of restitution and it's definition and that it is treated as a constant.
This was termed "Newton's law of restitution".

However, I don't seem to understand why that would seem to be. It seems pretty arbitrary why it would hold true. (No rigours or intuitive proof).

If there is one, I haven't seemed to find it online. (As there is for other laws like ohms law and Newton's law of cooling *)

Although I have accepted it to be a fact (to solve questions). I can not imagine it (COR) being anything more than a fancy way to give us an extra information which was previously missing.(As I have noticed with impulse-momentum equations).

I would like to gain some theoretical insight to why it is treated as a constant.(Or over a range of values)

(*By the proofs of the laws, what I meant:
Newton's law of cooling is an approximation of the Stephen-Boltzmann equation which is understood well.
Also ohms law can be "derived" through knowledge of drift velocity/relaxation time/Electric field. Which is what I am looking for.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Law of Restitution is usually stated as a constant ratio $e$ between relative velocities of separation and approach for a particular pair of colliding objects. A more intuitive formulation is that a constant fraction $1-e^2$ of the total kinetic energy lost in the collision.

Like Ohm's Law and Hooke's Law, the Law of Restitution is empirical. It is an approximation which is valid over a limited range of relative speeds of approach, typically 0.1 to 100 m/s. For some materials, notably rubber, which does not obey Hooke's law, it not a good approximation over this range. The law is not based on theory, but models of deformable materials can be used to "explain" how $e$ depends on the material, geometric and kinetic properties of the colliding bodies.

According to K L Thornton in [Contact Mechanics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Do6WQlUwbpkC&dq=Contact+Mechanics+and+Coefficients+of+Restitution&source=gbs_navlinks_s), CUP 1987, chapter 11, p 363 :

> The coefficient of restitution is not a material property, but depends on the severity of the impact. At sufficiently low velocities $V \lt V_Y$ the deformation is elastic and $e \approx 1$. The coefficient of restitution falls gradually with increasing velocity. When a fully plastic indentation is formed our theory suggests that $e \propto V^{-1/4}$.

For low impact speeds all colliding bodies behave like a spring and dashpot. The deformation is elastic, in the sense that the body returns to its original shape, but some energy is lost due to internal friction ([elastic hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Elastic_hysteresis)). The amount of frictional loss relates to the speed of sound waves $c$ in the material. If the material is very hard (stiff), so that the deformation is small and $c \gg V$ then almost all of the stored energy is returned as kinetic energy ($e \approx 1$). For 'soft' materials ($V \approx c$) a significant portion of the KE is lost ($e \lt 1$).

Thornton's analysis suggests that collisions cease to be elastic ($e \approx 1$) when $p=\rho V^2/Y \lt 10^{-6}$, where $\rho$ is density, $V$ is impact speed and $Y$ is the yield stress of the softer material. For a hard steel sphere striking a medium hard steel floor the impact speed at which plastic deformation starts is $V_Y \approx 0.14 m/s$. Thereafter permanent deformation occurs in part of the contact region, and the size of this region increases as impact velocity increases. Fully plastic deformation occurs for $p \approx 10^{-3}$ when typically $V \approx 5m/s$, above which the $V^{-1/4}$ law dominates.

The shallow indentation theory breaks down at $p \approx 10^{-1}, V \approx 100m/s$. The onset of hydrodynamic flow at $p \approx 10, V \approx 1000m/s$ is marked by  plastic deformation outside the contact region.